# robot_arm1:3: error: expected unqualified-id before '/' token

Tags: arduino

can anyone help with this error message?
Just bought an arduino uno & stuck already
Many thanks

robot_arm1:3: error: expected unqualified-id before '/' token

```
*/

pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

Serial.print("Initializing SD card..."); // make sure that the default chip select pin is set to // output, even if you don't use it: pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

// see if the card is present and can be initialized: if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) { Serial.println("Card failed, or not present"); // don't do anything more: return; } Serial.println("card initialized.");

}

void loop() {
```

Comment: Please add more code and format it. Indicate what is the line that make the error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to paste the full code but stackoverflow have a limit.

Comment: The full code is here: https://github.com/Dileepmeom/Arduino-Robotic-Arm---Copt-Cat/commit/d11fb86573a43bebe0f71824b45c313ac2cb32ae and I would love to get this working as it would be awesome! Can you see if it works on your ide? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to have an extra '*/' in the beginning
Try removing that token and the code should compile.
Alternatively, could you post a bigger chunk of your code, before and after the problematic line?